# Можно ли Get запросом выделить нужную radio button?

Tags: запрос, form, get

Вопрос следующий, как отправкой get запроса например localhost?name=yes, выделить нужную radio button в форме?если с radio это сделать нельзя то можно ли это сделать с selectom или ,  с chekbox?

Comment: Опять без библиотек ничего сделать не могут. Radio кнопки, как и select по приходу на сервер имеют свойство Имя=Значение. Имя - это имя элемента, которое вы сами сочиняете. Значение - это вариант из предложенных вами (разработчиком) вариантов для данной группы radio-кнопок или значение value тега option который входит в тег select.

Comment: При формировании группы (radio или select) вы сравниваете пришедшее значение относящееся к имени интересуемой переменной с формируемыми значениями value для radio кнопок или option тега select. В случае совпадения устанавливаете атрибут для radio - checked="checked" для option - selected="selected".

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, могу подсказать как это сделать на **jQuery**:

`$(document).ready(function(){
  var radio = $('#myRadio').prop('checked'); //Отбираем radio с ID myRadio
  if(radio == true){
    alert('Вы кликнули по Радио');
  }
});`

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="radio" value="someValue" <? if ($_GET['name'] == 'yes') echo 'checked' ?> />
```

Как то так, не?

Comment: не получается, потому что <input type="radio"> выводятся foreach, как-то можно по id поймать нужный инпут? желательно на javascript

Comment: @ochumelec, давайте не будим гадать на кофейной гуще, и вы добвите в вопрос хоть какойто код!

Comment: ок, движок opencart, файл product.tpl
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'image') { ?>
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?><input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
            <?php } ?>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>

Comment: @gooda, вам сюда http://govnokod.ru/